# groovy map usage difficulty in creating (slightly) complex data structures

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to query a database and store the results in a Groovy map data structure with some nested data elements and can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my latest attempt -

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.sql.Sql;

// code to connect to database omitted

TreeMap tsMap = [:];

def tabcount = 0, inxcount = 0;

dbconn.eachRow("SELECT table_name,tablespace_name FROM user_tables") {
    tabcount += 1;
    if (tsMap.containsKey(it.tablespace_name)) {
        tsMap[it.tablespace_name].tabs++;
    } else {
        type = [tabs:1];
        tsMap[it.tablespace_name] = type;
    }
}

dbconn.eachRow("SELECT index_name,tablespace_name FROM user_indexes") {
    inxcount += 1;
    if (tsMap.containsKey(it.tablespace_name) {
        tsMap[it.tablespace_name].inxs++;
    } else {
        type = [inxs:1];
        tsMap[it.tablespace_name] = type;
    }
}

tsMap.eachWithIndex { entry, i ->
    printf("%3d - Tablespace: %-30s contains %4d tables and %4d indexes\n",
            i, entry.key, entry.value.tabs, entry.value.inxs);
}

printf("Total table count = %d\n", tabcount);
printf("Total index count = %d\n", inxcount);
```

And here's what I want tsMap to end up with -

```
tsMap = [TS1:[tabs:10], TS2:[tabs:35, inxs:12]]
```

The TS1 entry (where there are only "table" entries and no "index" entries) works but as soon as there are also index entries I end up with -

```
tsMap = [TS1:[tabs:10], TS2:[inxs:12]]
```

even though TS2 also has 35 tables in addition to the 12 indexes.

My goal is to get tsMap to look like -

```
tsMap = [TS1:[tabs:10], TS2:[tabs:35, inxs:12]]
```

I use associative arrays in other languages and run into similar challenges anytime attempting to store arrays (of any kind) in them to create complex data structures.  With Groovy's Java underpinning I expected it to be easy and straightforward but if so then I'm missing something.

I'm already not happy with the complexity of this code as is and would appreciate pointers on how to simplify it.  I expected this to be very simple and straightforward, even trivial, and I took a wrong turn somewhere and it's anything but simple at this point.

Obviously I could just have two maps and end up with -

```
tabMap = [TS1:10, TS2:35]
inxMap = [TS2:12]
```

but of course this is also an exercise in understanding how to go beyond simple associative arrays (maps) so any help would be appreciated as I'm working on my Groovy skills.

So based on @cfrick's feedback I've tried this, much more streamlined code -

```
TreeMap tsMap = [:].withDefault{ [tabs:0, inxs:0] };

def tabcount = 0, inxcount = 0;

workconn.eachRow("SELECT table_name,tablespace_name FROM user_tables") {
    tsMap[it.tablespace_name].tabs++;
}

workconn.eachRow("SELECT index_name,tablespace_name FROM user_indexes") {
    tsMap[it.tablespace_name].inxs++;
}
```

which really seemed to make sense and I thought it was going to do it but I end up with -

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'tabs' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'tabs' on null object
```

which previously I've learned is because Groovy can't find that nested map with the "tabs" key to be able to increment it.

I thought the .withDefault was going to add my nested map to any "key" that I added to the tsMap.

Any advice on where I've gone wrong is appreciated.

---

## SOLUTION

OK, with @cfrick's help the objective is now working and here's the final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.sql.Sql;

// code to connect to database omitted

// avoid types other than def as they cast away the .withDefault
def tsMap = [:].withDefault{ [tabs:0, inxs:0] };

workconn.eachRow("SELECT table_name,NVL(tablespace_name, '(null)') tsName FROM user_tables") {
    tsMap[it.tsName].tabs++;
}

workconn.eachRow("SELECT index_name,NVL(tablespace_name, '(null)') tsName FROM user_indexes") {
    tsMap[it.tsName].inxs++;
}

def fmt = (opt.geninput) ? "%d,%s,%d,%d,%s\n" : "%3d - Tablespace: %-25s contains %4d tables and %4d indexes %s\n";

tsMap = tsMap.sort();  // sort the keys

tsMap.eachWithIndex { entry, i ->
    printf(fmt, i, entry.key, entry.value.tabs, entry.value.inxs, (entry.value.tabs * entry.value.inxs != 0) ? "**" : "");
}

printf("Total table count = %d\n", tsMap.values()*.tabs.sum());
printf("Total index count = %d\n", tsMap.values()*.inxs.sum());
```

Thanks!

Comment: since you are interested in optimizations: why not get the counts from the DB in the first place? `SELECT index_name,tablespace_name,count(*) from x group by tablespace_name, index_name`.  next you could "prefill" your tsmap from the beginning with `tsmap = [:].withDefault{ [tabs:0, inxs: 0] }`.  also you dont have to do the running total by hand: `tsmap.values()*.tabs.sum()` (and the same for index)

Comment: Thanks!  It doesn't exactly teach me what I was expecting but probably teaches me what I should have been looking for!

Comment: use `def` instead of `TreeMap` for `withDefault` on assignment or else it "gets cast away".  if you don't like this approach use `get(key, default)` (e.g. `tsMap.get(it.tablespace_name, [tabs:0, inxs:0]).inxs++`), but make sure you create a new default each time.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense now that I think about it.  I was using TreeMap because it sorts the keys.  Looks like I'll need to figure out how to sort the keys in that bit where I'm doing the `tsMap.eachWithIndex` thing.